# Get From Value from RLP

Tags: go-ethereum

How can I get `from` value from RLP Txn. Or How can I get signed user using R & S value. Currently I am using go ethereum.

Please help me.

Comment: what language ?

Comment: @Nulik I'm using golang

Answer (score -1):

key sentences are:

```
        tx_encoded,_ := hex.DecodeString(rlp_encoded_tx_hex)
        var tx types.Transaction
        rlp.DecodeBytes(tx_encoded,&tx)
```

imports are

```
"github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/rlp"
"github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/types"
```